# Is it possible to install a Helm dependency from a git repo?

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I have a Helm library chart that I can install as a dependency by including it in the same repo and using the filepath, like this:

```
dependencies:
  - name: foo-lib
    version: 1.0.0
    repository: file://../foo-lib
```

But once I move the library chart to it's own git repo, every syntax I've tried has been unable to install the chart using `helm dependency update`. The error says "...is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 121: mapping values are not allowed in this context", but I don't think it's a yaml conversion issue since I can install the chart with the filepath reference. Is it just completely impossible to do this? If not, what is the syntax?

```
dependencies:
  - name: foo-lib
    version: "1.0.0"
    repository: "https://github.com/bar/library-charts.git/foo-lib"
```